# Get value from array that is closest to but small than another value

Tags: swift

I have the following array:

```
let array = [0.0, 4.5, 5.6, 16.4, 16.7]
```

Given the a random number find out which value in the array is less than but closest to.

Examples

```
Value = 5.5 //result should be 4.5 from array
Value = 5.7 //result should be 5.6 from array
Value = 0.1 //result should be 0.0 from array
Value = 200.0 //result should be 16.7 from array
```

So far I have this code which tests for a great number but not a closest smaller number

```
var resultNext = 100.0
if let nextResult = self.pointDataForActivity.first(where: { $0 > Value }) {
print("The first greater number is \(nextResult).")
resultNext = nextResult
}
```

Comment: If your array is sorted then do a binary search to find lower bound

Comment: If there is a *greater than*  operator (`>`), there is certainly also one *less than*. Please have a look in the [Language Guide](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID70)